# cross-user C# mutex

Tags: c#, mutex

My app is forced to use a 3rd party module which will blue-screen Windows if two instances are started at the same time on the same machine.  To work around the issue, my C# app has a mutex:

```
static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{MyApp_b9d19f99-b83e-4755-9b11-d204dbd6d096}");
```

And I check if it's present - and if so I show an error message and close the app:

```
bool IsAnotherInstanceRunning()
{
    if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}
```

The problem is if two users can log in and open the application at the same time, and IsAnotherInstanceRunning() will return false.

How do I get around this?

Comment: How does the 3rd party module do that?  Have you contacted their support?

Comment: Unless it is a Kernel-level driver, it is surprisingly difficult to make Windows blue-screen these days - what in the world is that module doing?

Comment: @BlueRaja: It's quite easy to blue-screen Windows from user mode. Did you ever try to kill csrss.exe?

Comment: The 3rd party module is a hardware device I shall not name :)

Comment: for an remote desktop enviroment i write an answer to this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77316562/207005

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Prefix the name of the mutex with "Global\".

```
static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Global\MyApp_b9d19f99-b83e-4755-9b11-d204dbd6d096");
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx:

> If its name begins with the prefix
>   "Global\", the mutex is visible in all
>   terminal server sessions. If its name
>   begins with the prefix "Local\", the
>   mutex is visible only in the terminal
>   server session where it was created.
>   In that case, a separate mutex with
>   the same name can exist in each of the
>   other terminal server sessions on the
>   server. If you do not specify a prefix
>   when you create a named mutex, it
>   takes the prefix "Local\".

Comment: I tried this method, but encounter an unhandled exception when trying to debug,I run VS as administrator, -----------      An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'Global\MDProduction' is denied.

Comment: You have to set MutexSecurity, like in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77316562/207005

Answer (score 15):

Change the mutex name to begin with `Global\`.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)

> On a server that is running Terminal
>   Services, a named system mutex can
>   have two levels of visibility. If its
>   name begins with the prefix "Global\",
>   the mutex is visible in all terminal
>   server sessions. If its name begins
>   with the prefix "Local\", the mutex is
>   visible only in the terminal server
>   session where it was created. In that
>   case, a separate mutex with the same
>   name can exist in each of the other
>   terminal server sessions on the
>   server. If you do not specify a prefix
>   when you create a named mutex, it
>   takes the prefix "Local\". Within a
>   terminal server session, two mutexes
>   whose names differ only by their
>   prefixes are separate mutexes, and
>   both are visible to all processes in
>   the terminal server session. That is,
>   the prefix names "Global\" and
>   "Local\" describe the scope of the
>   mutex name relative to terminal server
>   sessions, not relative to processes.