# atomic operations on a file from different processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, locking, atomic

I need to work with a single file (read and write) from DIFFERENT processes. Since there is a competition between processes, it is necessary to block the file. Currently recording is implemented as follows:

```
const int MAX_RETRY = 50;
const int DELAY_MS = 200;
bool Success = false;
int Retry = 0;
while (!Success && Retry < MAX_RETRY)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter Wr = new StreamWriter(ConfPath))
        {
            Wr.WriteLine("My content");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(DELAY_MS);
        Retry++;
    }
}
```

Is there a proper solution to my problem?

Comment: Do both processes do both read and write operations?

Comment: Both processes can read and write to a file.

Comment: you can use mutex see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830546/cross-user-c-sharp-mutex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Named Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.110).aspx) to share a lock between processes:

```
const int MAX_RETRY = 50;
const int DELAY_MS = 200;
bool Success = false;
int Retry = 0;

// Will return an existing mutex if one with the same name already exists
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "MutexName"); 
mutex.WaitOne();

try
{
    while (!Success && Retry < MAX_RETRY)
    {
        using (StreamWriter Wr = new StreamWriter(ConfPath))
        {
            Wr.WriteLine("My content");
        }
        Success = true;
    }
}
catch (IOException)
{
  Thread.Sleep(DELAY_MS);
  Retry++;
}
finally
{
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: If all the processes that access the file, will use mutex, then I'll be able to do so: http://pastebin.com/9MhaSzTs
Will it work?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of a shared mutex. When creating it by name, and will return the already constructed mutex.